# File "/scratch/tmp/pip-install-8emz1jxb/parallel/pprocess.py", line 255 raise AcknowledgementError, obj SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pip, anaconda

I am not sure how to get this fixed. My pip version is 18.1:
Installing the parallel package from PyCharm:

```
Collecting parallel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/5b/66966fb4d103191b7cbc92730db6a335986fbdb3d9f55cbb54b7ba87e9d4/parallel-0.2.5.tar.gz (57kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/scratch/tmp/pycharm-packaging/parallel/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import pprocess
      File "/scratch/tmp/pycharm-packaging/parallel/pprocess.py", line 255
        raise AcknowledgementError, obj
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------

  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /scratch/tmp/pycharm-packaging/parallel/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Installing the PyCharm package from terminal:

```
$  pip3  install --user  parallel
Collecting parallel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/5b/66966fb4d103191b7cbc92730db6a335986fbdb3d9f55cbb54b7ba87e9d4/parallel-0.2.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/scratch/tmp/pip-install-8emz1jxb/parallel/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import pprocess
      File "/scratch/tmp/pip-install-8emz1jxb/parallel/pprocess.py", line 255
        raise AcknowledgementError, obj
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 

    /scratch/tmp/pip-install-8emz1jxb/parallel/
    [jalal@goku]$  pip3  install --user  pandas
    Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.22.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.6.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2017.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas) (1.11.0)



$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)
$ which pip
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded & opened the tar.gz file from that pypi cache url to make sure, and confirmed that what you were trying to do was to install a module that was both *abandoned* & didn't even *passed status alpha since 2007*, for Python 3. That will never work. I'd suggest not to install the author recommendation module as well given that it's also isn't maintained since 2016.
https://pypi.org/project/parallel/0.2.5%20(deprecated%20-%20see%20pprocess)/

Answer (score 0):

You can use
"from joblib import Parallel,delayed".
just install joblib.